# Bank of log messages in Spring

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I am using org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger for logging:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MainController.class)
```

and then

```
logger.info("Register request from " + User.getUuid());
```

I want to hold all the messages of the repository that the logger generate in  one place, such as a properties file, so that I could send them easily to review of technical publication department.

For instance, ideally there would be a file (let's call it messages.properties) which will hold the following:

register_request_from_user_uuid="Register request from " + User.getUuid()

Is there a way to do it in Spring? Are there any alternative ways to hold a bank of all the log messages? Are you familiar with a tool that might orchestrate it?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any chance you could upgrade to slf4j? In that case, string placeholders would be a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example, you can modify it according to your needs:

In your `src/main/resources` create a file `messages.properties` with contents:

```
test.message=TEST MESSAGE {0}
```

`{0}` is the "parameter" to pass to the localized string, (`+ User.getUuid()` in your sample)

Then you can call your `logger` as:

```
logger.debug(MarkerManager.getMarker("TEST"), 
            new LocalizedMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages"), "test.message", "hello!"));
```

Again the 3rd parameter `"hello"` is concatenated to the `{0}` placeholder defined in the `messages.properties` above.

the output printed to the console is:

`2018-12-05 15:12:09.902 DEBUG 23376 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.SpringDemoApplication   : TEST MESSAGE: hello!`

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!